# Kotlin extensions method

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-extension

How can I write extension function in kotlin for such function:

```
public abstract fun <T : TargetValue> getAverage(metric: StatisticsMetric, 
interval: DateInterval, 
timeUnit: TimeUnit,
mode: GroupingMode /* = compiled code */, 
result: (AsyncResult<kotlin.collections.Map<Info, T>, Error>) -> kotlin.Unit): kotlin.Unit
```

To be able call it like  this:
TargetValueV2 : TargetValue

```
"This function about signature".asFlow(): Flow<MyCustomDataEvent>

        val flowResult = sdk.getAverage<TargetValueV2>(
            metric = TIME,
            interval = DateInterval(startDay, currentDate),
            timeUnit = DAY,
            mode = private
        ).asFlow()
```

Comment: To me, your question doesn't make any sense. Please try to state clearly what you want to achieve

Comment: You mean you want to convert this callback-based function into a suspend function? What is the return type you expect? `AsyncResult`? What is the `asFlow()` function that you want to call on it? What is the type of `sdk`? Is the provided `getAverage` an existing method in the type of `sdk`? Many details are lacking if you want to get proper help on this

Comment: not clear what you try to do.

Comment: `extension functions` are functions with `receiver` (shugar to not use it as first parameter). For example `fun String.trimQuotes() = trim('"','\'')` but sygnature you provide is not an extnsion, but has tail function parameter. Next you post `example of use` - where we see it as extension on something `sdk` but without tail function - what exactly you mean?